# Coordinator Layout reset position when scrolling up or down

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout, coordinator-layout

I have a `CoordinatorLayout` with an `AppBarLayout` and a `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. In `CollapsingToolbarLayout` I'm using a `LinearLayout` showing **user info** as a `layout_collapseMode=parallax` element, below of it, a `TabLayout`.

The behaviour that I expect is a smooth hiding of the **user info** while the `TabLayout` is scrolling up or down.

**The problem is** that the items positions are reset when I scroll down a bit, hiding entirely the **user info** layout.

```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/home_green_gradient"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:elevation="2dp">

        <!-- user info -->
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="244dp"
                android:clipChildren="false"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/profile_store_index_layout"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/profile_imageview"
                    android:background="@drawable/home_small_circle_background"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_store_white_18dp"
                        android:tint="@color/up_green"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:text="100%"
                        android:textColor="@color/white_color"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/profile_imageview"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/dummy_worker_office"
                    app:border_color="@color/dark_green"
                    app:border_width="6dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/profile_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/profile_imageview"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Juan Rojas Torres"
                    android:textColor="@color/white_color"
                    android:textSize="18sp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/profile_company_executions"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/profile_name"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="User name"
                    android:textColor="@color/dark_green_text"
                    android:textSize="12sp"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/profile_company_executions"
                    android:src="@drawable/bottom_image"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <!-- Tabs at bottom -->
            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragment_fragment_tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="@color/dark_green"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/frogmi_indicator_color"
                app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/frogmi_white_color"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/frogmi_non_selected_green_text"/>
            </FrameLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>



    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/fragment_fragment_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

```